# Unit Of Measure Used In jszpl

Tags: node.js, zpl

I use `jszpl` to generate `.zpl` within my `Nodejs` application. Many elements have properties referencing a size, but I can't find anywhere what the unit of measure is. I thought the unit of measure was millimeters, but I was finding that is not the case based on my testing.

For example:

```
const text1 = new Text();<br/>
label.content.push(text1);<br/>
text1.fontFamily = new FontFamily(FontFamilyName.F);<br/>
text1.horizontalAlignment = new Alignment(AlignmentValue.Center);<br/>
**text1.top = 44;**<br/>
text1.text = 'Roll ID';
```

I thought in this example I was setting the text to generate 44mm from the top of the parent, but that is not the case.

Does anyone know what unit of measure is being used?

Answer (score 2):

The standard unit of measurement in ZPL is dot. It is also mentioned in [JSZPL github](https://github.com/DanieLeeuwner/JSZPL) that the measurement unit used in the library is dot. Now, what is dot?

Dot is a variable size unit, its size depends on dpi (dots per inch) setting of the printer. It can have values 152, 203, 300, 600, although not all printers support all of them. Usually supported values are 203 and 300 dpi. You can set this directly on the printer via buttons, via web GUI (if you are using network connection), Zebra setup utilities or by using the [^MU ZPL command](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf#G148.1036061).

So, the size of a dot is determined by dpi setting. Lets say that your printer is set up to 203 dpi and you are using value 44 in your code. As the name suggests, 203 dpi means 203 dots per inch, so the real world length is 44/203 inch. To convert it to milimeters it would be (44/203)*25,4 mm. In case of 300 dpi just swap the 203 value with 300.

More about [ZPL basics in ZPL manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf#G5.1150471) or in [Labelary introduction to ZPL](http://labelary.com/zpl.html).
You can also try [Labelary Online ZPL viewer](http://labelary.com/viewer.html) where you can change dpi settings and experiment on what does it do to your code.